# Jquery doesn't work after a callback is performed

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cheader = document.getElementsByClassName("centralheader");
    var cmain = document.getElementsByClassName("centralmain");
    var eheader = document.getElementsByClassName("esbheader");
    var emain = document.getElementsByClassName("esbmain");
    var lheader = document.getElementsByClassName("LMheader");
    var lmain = document.getElementsByClassName("LMmain");
    var pheader = document.getElementsByClassName("promoheader");
    var pmain = document.getElementsByClassName("promomain");

    $(cheader).click(function () {
        $(cmain).toggle("slow");
    });
    $(eheader).click(function () {
        $(emain).toggle("slow");
    });
    $(lheader).click(function () {
        $(lmain).toggle("slow");
    });
    $(pheader).click(function () {
        $(pmain).toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I'm using DevExpress controls so its an `ASPxCallbackPanel`. My first problem was referencing my div's because they are wrapped in the `ASPxCallbackPanel` so I was having an issue being able to find them. Now it seems that when first loading the page, the JQuery works fine but it's as soon as a callback completes that the JQuery isn't working. Once a callback has finished and I go to click on div - cheader(for example), it will not register the click and will not toggle the div - cmain.

Comment: what is `Dcs`? Do you get any JS error when looking at the console?

Comment: What's an aspxcallback panel? Do you mean an UpdatePanel? If you're using an UpdatePanel to replace, cheader, for example, the click handler will no longer be registered. UpdatePanel removes its contents from the DOM and reads them. You'd need to reregister the click handler.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and DOM to get the elements? My guess is the fact you are trying to find an element before it exists on the page. It is like someone calling your name when you are not in the room. You are not going to hear it.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using devxpress controls so its an aspxcallbackpanel. My first problem was referencing my div's because they are wrapped in the aspxcallbackpanel so I was having an issue being able to find them. Now it seems that when first loading the page, the jquery works fine but it's as soon as  a callback completes that the jquery isn't working. I'm a little bit stuck...

Comment: Updated example to show a better `data-` driven approach. Hope it helps. It will certainly make maintenance easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the content is dynamic, use delegated event handlers, attached to a non-changing ancestor element (`document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient).

This works by connecting single events to an ancestor (e.g. `document`), then listening for the event (click) to bubble up to it. It *then* applies the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble-chain *at event time*. It *the* applies the callback to only the matching elements *that caused the event*.

The upshot of this is that the elements only need to match the selector when the click occurs and not when the event was registered.

e.g.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.centralheader', function () {
        $(".centralmain").toggle("slow");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.esbheader', function () {
        $('.esbmain').toggle("slow");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.LMheader', function () {
        $('.LMmain').toggle("slow");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.promoheader', function () {
        $('.promomain').toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

### Notes:

- In your example, there is no need to pre-fetch the elements using `document.getElementsByClassName` as jQuery does that in a simpler way.
- `$(function () {` is a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`
- A DOM ready handler is not actually required for the code shown as `document` always exists.
- As jQuery can chain elements/functions, you can shorten it to:

**Chained version:**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.centralheader', function () {
        $(".centralmain").toggle("slow");
    }).on('click', '.esbheader', function () {
        $('.esbmain').toggle("slow");
    }).on('click', '.LMheader', function () {
        $('.LMmain').toggle("slow");
    }).on('click', '.promoheader', function () {
        $('.promomain').toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

## Another better(?) way:

A better alternative (IMHO) is to `data-` drive any scenario like this.

It involves having a common class on the elements you want to click (e.g. `header`) and the elements you click contain a reference to the item you want to  modify (e.g. a `data-` attribute with a jQuery selector).

e.g.

```
<div class="header" data-target=".centralmain">Central header</div>
<div class="header" data-target=".centralmain">ESB header</div>
<div class="header" data-target=".centralmain">LM header</div>
<div class="header" data-target=".promomain">Promo header</div>
```

The code then becomes something as simple as this (long version for readability first):

```
$(document).on('click', '.header', function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var target = $this.data("target");
     $(target).toggle('slow');
});
```

Which compresses to this tiny snippet:

```
$(document).on('click', '.header', function(){
     $($(this).data("target")).toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: No problem. There is a better way of doing this entire thing *if you are interested*. That just uses common classes and `data-` attributes to determine the target to toggle. The code then becomes a single click handler with the cross-linking maintained in the HTML. An Example of your HTML (saved from browser, not source code) would help illustrate this.